# Redirect system audio into microphone

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, microphone, speakers

So, yesterday, i was calling with my friend and i wanted to play him an sound from a game, but i had no idea how, because he couldn't hear mine sound. So, is there a way to direct all the system audio to record on the microphone? And also keep the normal output so i can hear it. Thanks for help!

And also, please make your answer noob-friendly, because i am pretty bad with this, thanks!

Other stuff:

I want to direct the output into the microphone, not just the calling program (it's Skype by the way). Please don't answer that i should put the output to the speakers and record it like it, because i don't even have speakers... just headphones. I know that you can record system audio on skype, but i want it for other purposes than through skype calling... and i also want it to be recorded live.

Comment: Enable stereo mix. See this [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/).

Comment: @Biswa that might be worth posting as answer, of course also include the summary of steps needed to enable it :)

Comment: @Vylix I'm not sure if it will work for OP's problem or not.

Comment: why not just record the sound with your smartphone and then play it back to the microphone?

Comment: @flowtron yeah, but i want to like record it live.